# How to free dynamically allocated memory in a linkedlist in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, malloc

I have tried to implement a linked list in C, and I have some memory leaks due to not freeing some of the malloc'd variables. I am not sure when and how to free them, as I cannot free them before using them.

This is my code for insertStart

```
void main()
{
   LinkedList* undo = createLinkedList();
   Position* place = (Position*)malloc(sizeof(Position));
   place->row = 1;
   place->col = 2;
   
   insertStart(undo, (void*)place);

}

void insertStart(LinkedList* list, void* entry)
{
    void* newEntry = malloc(sizeof(Position));
    ListNode* newNd = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    memcpy(newEntry, entry, sizeof(Position));

    newNd->data = newEntry;
    newNd->next = list->head;
    list->head = newNd;

    list->size++;
}
```

I am getting the leak from the line `void* newEntry = malloc(sizeof(Position));`

I tried to use valgrind and this is what it outputs,

```
==1385==
==1385== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1385==     in use at exit: 900 bytes in 19 blocks
==1385==   total heap usage: 78 allocs, 59 frees, 14,808 bytes allocated
==1385==
==1385== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 7
==1385==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1385==    by 0x109668: controls (game.c:78)
==1385==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1385==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:49)
==1385==
==1385== 48 bytes in 2 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 2 of 7
==1385==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1385==    by 0x10AA5B: insertStart (linkedList.c:24)
==1385==    by 0x109829: controls (game.c:114)
==1385==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1385==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:49)
==1385==
==1385== 48 bytes in 2 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 3 of 7
==1385==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1385==    by 0x10AA5B: insertStart (linkedList.c:24)
==1385==    by 0x1099F2: controls (game.c:144)
==1385==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1385==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:49)
==1385==
==1385== 120 bytes in 5 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 4 of 7
==1385==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1385==    by 0x10AA5B: insertStart (linkedList.c:24)
==1385==    by 0x109910: controls (game.c:129)
==1385==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1385==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:49)
==1385==
==1385== 168 bytes in 7 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 5 of 7
==1385==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1385==    by 0x10AA5B: insertStart (linkedList.c:24)
==1385==    by 0x109AD9: controls (game.c:159)
==1385==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1385==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:49)
==1385==
==1385== 408 (24 direct, 384 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 7
==1385==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1385==    by 0x10AA5B: insertStart (linkedList.c:24)
==1385==    by 0x109AD9: controls (game.c:159)
==1385==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1385==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:49)
==1385==
==1385== 472 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 7 of 7
==1385==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1385==    by 0x48DF64D: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==1385==    by 0x48DF64D: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==1385==    by 0x109347: main (main.c:26)
==1385==
==1385== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1385==    definitely lost: 44 bytes in 2 blocks
==1385==    indirectly lost: 384 bytes in 16 blocks
==1385==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1385==    still reachable: 472 bytes in 1 blocks
==1385==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1385==
==1385== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==1385== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I have also searched it up and tried to implement this deleteAll method, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

I have updated my deleteAll function and now this it the Valgrind output.

```
==3055==
==3055== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3055==     in use at exit: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==3055==   total heap usage: 72 allocs, 71 frees, 14,676 bytes allocated
==3055==
==3055== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==3055==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3055==    by 0x10AA80: insertStart (linkedList.c:22)
==3055==    by 0x109A1E: controls (game.c:144)
==3055==    by 0x1095C2: game (game.c:44)
==3055==    by 0x109475: main (main.c:49)
==3055==
==3055== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3055==    definitely lost: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==3055==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3055==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3055==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3055==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3055==
==3055== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Now it is saying that the leak is coming from `void* newEntry = malloc(sizeof(Position));`

Comment: Your insert func has 2 calls to `malloc`, so the delete func should probably have 2 calls to `free`.

Comment: And don't forget about the `malloc` in `createLinkedList`.

Comment: I suggest to [edit] the question and show a [mre]. Unrelated to the memory leak: You pass `void* entry` to the function, but allocate and copy the size of `Position`. This means the pointer must point to some structure/array/memory of at least `sizeof(Position)` to avoid undefined behavior in `memcpy` and it should be not more than `sizeof(Position)` to avoid data loss. So it should point to a `Position` or something of the same size. If you want to implement a generic function you might have to pass the size of the data structure you want to store in addition to the pointer,

Comment: What is `Position` and why do you feel an urge to `malloc` memory for it inside a **generic** `LinkedList` implementation?

Comment: Aside: In the code block at the top of this question, there are 3 invocations of `malloc()`... Two of those use _casting_ but one doesn't. Did you know that _casting_ the returned pointer from `malloc()` is not necessary and is considered a bad practice in C? (We'll leave verifying the success of the allocation for another day...)

Comment: Casting as in this line `ListNode* newNd = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));` ?

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: "I have updated my deleteAll function". OK, so where is the updated version and the original version? Please keep the original code in addition to any updated functions.

Comment: In your edited code, in `main()`, you have `Position* place = (Position*)malloc(sizeof(Position));` which is never freed. That probably accounts for the 1 definitely lost block reported by ValGrind, although you have not shown any calls to `deleteAll()`.

Answer (score 3):

`deleteAll` is only freeing one of the blocks allocated by `insertStart`. Also, I don't know if you want it to also free the block allocated by `createLinkedList`. The `temp` variable in `deleteAll` is actually pointing to a `Position`, not a `ListNode`.

Try this:

```
void deleteAll(LinkedList* list)
{
    while (list->head != NULL)
    {
        ListNode* temp = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        free(temp->data);
        free(temp);
    }
    free(list); // not sure if you want this or not
}
```

Here is a complete example using the function. Error checking of the `malloc` return values has been omitted:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct listNode ListNode;

struct listNode
{
    struct listNode *next;
    void *data;
};

typedef struct
{
    ListNode *head;
    ListNode *tail;
    unsigned int size;
} LinkedList;

typedef struct
{
    int row;
    int col;
} Position;

LinkedList* createLinkedList(void)
{
    LinkedList* newList;
    newList = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    newList->head = NULL;
    newList->tail = NULL;
    newList->size = 0;
   
    return newList;
}

void insertStart(LinkedList* list, void* entry)
{
    void* newEntry = malloc(sizeof(Position));
    ListNode* newNd = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    memcpy(newEntry, entry, sizeof(Position));

    newNd->data = newEntry;
    newNd->next = list->head;
    list->head = newNd;
    // I added the following bit to set list->tail ...
    if (newNd->next == NULL)
    {
        list->tail = newNd;
    }
    list->size++;
}

void deleteAll(LinkedList* list)
{
    while (list->head != NULL)
    {
        ListNode* temp = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        free(temp->data);
        free(temp);
    }
    free(list);
}

int main(void)
{
    LinkedList* undo = createLinkedList();
    Position place = { .row = 1, .col = 2 };
    insertStart(undo, &place);
    deleteAll(undo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked, thanks!

Comment: I used valgrind and another time and now it says that there is a memory leak from the

`void* newEntry = malloc(sizeof(Position));`

Comment: @Cindy_l providing the requested minimal reproducible example would allow us to provide better help.

Comment: I was told that editing and removing part of my question isn't preferred, so I just added onto my question. Should rearrange my question or should I just start a new question with MRE

Comment: @Cindy_l No, you did not just add to your question. You renamed and removed functions. What you were asked for would mean you should add the missing parts to make it a compilable program. Your change made existing answers useless.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback, will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

It is very convenient to think about two programmers, the one who writes the linked list code and another one who *uses* the linked list code written by the first programmer. Even if you do both jobs, you have to think about them separately.

There are four possible valid scenarios.

- The user that uses the list code allocates the data, and he is also responsible for freeing the data somewhere in his own code.
- The implementor of the linked list allocates the data (perhaps somewhere in the function that allocates a list node), and he is also responsible for freeing the data (perhaps somewhere in a function that frees a list node).
- The user allocates the data, but hands over the responsibility for freeing it to the implementor. This is rare, don't do that unless you know exactly why you need it and how to do it properly.
- The implementor allocates the data, but the user is responsible for freeing it. This is non-existent in the real world, don't do that, ever.

Your code implements the fifth scenario: the implementor allocates the data, but completely forgets to free it. Alas it is not a valid one.

Code that implements the first scenario would look like this:

```
void insertStart(LinkedList* list, void* entry)
{
  ListNode* newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
  newNode->next = list->head;
  newNode->data = entry;  // <---- pay attention to this
  list->head = newNode;
  list->size++;
}
```

That's it. Of course the *user* will need to make sure they call `malloc` and `free` the same number of times. Note that the implementor doesn't know and doesn't care what kind of data is to be stored in the list, hence the `void` pointer. The `deleteAll` function doesn't change.

Code that implements the second scenario would look very differently. Since the list code *knows* what kind of data is to be stored, it is best to reflect this knowledge in the *types*.

```
typedef struct node
{
  Position* data;
  struct node* next;
} ListNode;

void insertStart(LinkedList* list, Position* entry)
{
  Position* newEntry = malloc(sizeof(*newEntry));
  *newEntry = *entry;
  // or: memcpy(newEntry, entry, sizeof(*newEntry));

  ListNode* newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));

  newNode->data = newEntry;
  newNode->next = list->head;
  list->head = newNd;
  list->size++;
}
```

Note how there are no `void` pointers. Since we know we work with the `Position` type, we might as well say it in the code. The `deleteAll` function would need to have an additional line or two

```
void deleteAll(LinkedList* list)
{
    while (list->head != NULL)
    {
        ListNode* temp = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        free(temp->data);  // <---- we allocated it, we free it
        free(temp);  // <---- we allocated it, we free it
    }
    free(list);  // <---- we allocated it, we free it
}
```

Now it's a good time to confess. I lied. There is another valid scenario, namely, *there is no data pointer*. The list node stores the data by value.

```
typedef struct node
{
   Position data;       // <---- No pointer
   struct node* next;
} ListNode;

void insertStart(LinkedList* list, void* entry)
{
  ListNode* newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
  newNode->next = list->head;
  newNode->data = *entry;  // <---- pay attention to this
  list->head = newNode;
  list->size++;
}
```

`deleteAll` just looses the `free(temp->data);` line. That's it.

The no pointer scenario is the one to be always preferred. Use pointers only if strictly necessary (for example, your professor tells you to --- or indeed you don't know what kind of data you store).

Comment: Thanks for this reply, I don't think I can change the void pointer into a Position pointer, as I have to leave the ListNode struct the way it is, as it is given by the assessment outline. I will try to read through and get a better understanding.

Comment: Is there another solution to this, as I can't changed the void pointer.

Comment: I normally show how to program, not how to satisfy those who "teach programming". I have no interest in the latter.

Comment: Of course, `newNode->data = *entry;` won't work because of the declaration `void* entry`.

Comment: @Cindy_l Having said that, if you have an assessment outline, you can *show it* and I can try to analyze it, break it into pieces, and make something sensible out of it (my gut feeling that it is not sensible as is but I am known to be wrong at times).